# Prove that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $H$ is generated by the set $ H- \{1\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

Prove that  if $H$  is a  subgroup of $G$  then $H$  is generated  by the set $ H- \{1\}$

**My attempt** : let $H$  be a  subgroup of $G$ . If $H=\{1\}$  then  $\langle H-\{1\} \rangle = \langle  \emptyset \rangle$ . This represent , $\langle \emptyset \rangle$  is the intersection of all subgroup $A$ of  $G$ such that $\emptyset \subseteq A \le G$

$\implies \langle \emptyset \rangle$ is the intersection  of all subgroups of $G$, so  $\langle H-\{1\} \rangle = \langle  \emptyset \rangle=  \{1\} =\langle  H \rangle \tag1$

Now suppose if  $H \neq \{1\}$ then $h \in H$ we have $1=hh^{-1} \in \langle H-\{1\} \rangle$

$\implies \langle H-\{1\} \rangle =  \{1\} =\langle  H \rangle \tag2 $

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we show that   if $H$  is a  subgroup of $G$  then $H$  is generated  by the set $ H- \{1\}$

Comment: Why $\langle H \rangle = \{1\}$ in $(2)$ if $H \neq \{1\}$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde  because $1 \in \langle H-\{1\} \rangle $

Comment: @jasmine I have posted an answer clarifying the second part of your proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right ideas, but I am not sure the writing is fully correct. (1) should probably be:

$$\langle H-\{1\} \rangle = \langle  \emptyset \rangle=  \{1\} =\color{red}{H}$$

As for (2):

$$\langle H-\{1\} \rangle =  \color{red}{\{1\}} =\langle  H \rangle$$

I am not sure what you want to say here, and the bit in red is incorrect. You have made the correct (and important) observation that $1\in\langle H-\{1\}\rangle$, and because,  obviously, $H-\{1\}\subset\langle H-\{1\}\rangle$, now you *could* say that

$$H = (H-\{1\})\cup \{1\}\subset\langle H-\{1\}\rangle$$

On the other hand, as $H-\{1\}\subset H$ and $H$ is a subgroup, then

$$\langle H-\{1\}\rangle \subset H$$

Finally, the two inclusions above prove that $H=\langle H-\{1\}\rangle$.

Answer (score 3):

Your argument for $H = \{1\}$ is correct. For $H \ne \{1\}$, you probably have the right idea in mind - but let me spell out the details properly.

Assume $H \ne \{1\}$. Certainly, $H - \{1\} \subset H$. $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, so $\langle H - \{1\}\rangle \subset H$. It suffices to prove that $H \subset \langle H - \{1\}\rangle$. As you correctly mentioned, since $H\ne \{1\}$, there exists $h\in H - \{1\}$ with $h\ne 1$. Also, $h^{-1} \in H - \{1\}$ since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. By definition, $hh^{-1} = 1 \in \langle H - \{1\}\rangle$. Since $1\in \langle H - \{1\}\rangle$ and $h\in \langle H - \{1\}\rangle$ for all $h\in H - \{1\}$, we get $H \subset \langle H - \{1\}\rangle$ as required. Therefore,
$$\boxed{H = \langle H - \{1\}\rangle}$$

Answer (score 1):

What you have for $H=\{1\}$ is correct.

There is a simple argument for the other case.

Note that $H\setminus \{1\}$ simply lists all nontrivial elements of $H$, and for any $h\in H\setminus \{1\}$, since $H\le G$, we have $ h^{-1}\in H\setminus \{1\}$, so that $1=hh^{-1}\in \langle H\setminus \{1\}\rangle$. Clearly there are no other elements in $\langle H\setminus \{1\}\rangle$. Hence $\langle H\setminus \{1\}\rangle =H$.

Comment: Replace $\{0\}$ by $\{1\}$. See my proof too - it's essentially the same.

Comment: Thank you, @delta-divine; corrected.